# Conflicts between Derby and JUnit 4?

Tags: spring, junit, junit4, derby, jbehave

In order to add some new ATDD testing features to our project(Using JBehave). I have updated my JUnit jar (4.4 -> 4.10) so that I can make use of the SpringAnnotatedEmbedderRunner class.

Since doing so, many of our unit tests are failing. All of which relate to our 'in memory' db derby:

```
Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'FIX_MESSAGE_SEQUENCES' does not exist.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.UpdateNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

Does anyone know if there is any known conflicts between derby and JUnit 4? or If there is any workaround?

Pom entries:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.9.1.0 </version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Table/view doesn't exist simply means that you haven't created the tables and views in your database. After connecting to Derby and creating your in-memory database, you need to create the tables and views that your application needs.

Comment: If only it was so simple :) Logs state that the tables are being created on start up. (When tests are run with either version of JUnit). However the newer version of JUnit causes these errors. There isd no change in the code what so ever.